# Show that the ring $R$ is Noetherian

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noetherian

Let 
$$R = \{ \frac{f(z)}{g(z)}: f, g \in \mathbb{C}[z], g(z) \neq 0 \text{ for } |z| = 1 \}.$$
Prove that $R$ is a Noetherian ring.

Note : $\mathbb C$ is the set of the complex numbers, $z$ is a complex variable, $f$ and $g$ are polynomials on the field of the complex numbers.

Comment: what is $C$? what is $Z$? what are $f, g$? **nothing is clear.**

Comment: $C$ is the set of the complex numbers , $Z$ is a complex variable , $f$ and $g$ are  polynomials on the field of the complex numbers  @Krish

Comment: @Krish but $C[Z]$ not $C[X]$

Comment: Please show your work, what you have tried to solve this, what you think might help, &c.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I tried over and over but nothing

Comment: @Bellypunching Well, what have you tried? Include that in your post.

Comment: You can observe that you're localizing at the set of $z-\zeta$ where $\zeta\notin S^1$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** Show that $R$ is a ring of fractions of $\mathbb C[z]$.